# wxPython instantiating new wxFrames and closing them freezes Python

Tags: python, thread-safety, wxpython, canopy

I'm trying to create wxFrames on the click on a button from the TopWindow of a wx application. Even though the frames are being instantiated, and I can clearly see them, when I close the application(the child frame), a few questions arise:

### Several Problems

- I can't open the same frame again. I'm not instantiating anything so I don't know why that would be the error.
- I can't close the parent frame in one click. The parent frame first removes all of its children in the app, and then I would have to click the red x button once more to close it.
- Upon closing the parent frame, I can't open up another instance from my IDE(I'm using Enthought Canopy). I would have to restart the python instance and then refresh.

### Illustration of the 2nd problem

Here's an illustration of the glitchy parent frame:

#### Before clicking the close button

[image]

#### After clicking the close button

[image]

I don't understand why this would be happening. Here is my code:

```
class AppManager(wx.Frame):
    CHOICES = {}
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # build a frame
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Image Calculator", size = (700, 170), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        frameSize = wx.DisplaySize()
        print frameSize
        self.CHOICES = {"ImageCalc2Beta": imageCalc(parent = None), 
        ... More wxFrames ...
        "DarkNoiseGrapherV3": DarkNoiseGrapherv3_Unstable(None, frameSize)}
        # build a panelz
    self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    
    # sizer
    self.buttonSizer = wx.GridSizer(4,0)
    # build buttons for selecting files ==================================================
    self.imageCalc2Beta = wx.Button(self.mainPanel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label = "Open ImageCalc2Beta")
    self.imageCalc2Beta.name = "ImageCalc2Beta"
    self.imageCalc2Beta.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openApp)
    ... more buttons binding to the event ...
    self.DarkNoiseGrapherV3 = wx.Button(self.mainPanel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label = "Open DarkNoiseGrapherV3")
    self.DarkNoiseGrapherV3.name = "DarkNoiseGrapherV3"
    self.DarkNoiseGrapherV3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.openApp)
    
    #adding buttons into sizer
    self.buttonSizer.Add(self.imageCalc2Beta)

    self.buttonSizer.Add(self.DarkNoiseGrapherV3)  
    
    #Setting sizer to panel
    self.mainPanel.SetSizer(self.buttonSizer)
    ... more adding buttons ...
    self.mainPanel.Layout()
        
    def openApp(self, event):
        self.frame = self.CHOICES[event.GetEventObject().name]
        self.frame.Show()
        
# below is needed for all GUIs
if __name__== '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False) # application object (inner workings) 
    frame = AppManager(parent = None) # frame object (what user sees)
    frame.Show() # show frame
    app.MainLoop() # run main loop
```

Note that each individual wxFrame child in the dictionary works independently. I'm just trying to create an application to consolidate them together.

Note: I tried to do this with a dummy wx.Frame but was not able to replicate the error, so I'm guessing it may be a part of my other wx.Frame applications' implementation. However, I don't know which parts of the code to display.

Comment: when a frame is closed it is typically destroyed ... you could bind to wx.EVT_CLOSE and simply hide the frame and not propagate the event if you do not want the frame to be de stroyed ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Right, but does destroying the frame render reinstantiation impossible? I will try that though and report back with the results, thank you! :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley that worked! Except I'm still having the trouble on the main frame's closing process.. I don't think I tinkered with anything so why would it close so strangely? It also forces me to restart python everytime(I'm guessing python still thinks it's running)

Comment: furthermore your example is not runnable in its current state ... between syntax error (where you are trying to `...show more ...` and custom classes that are not included) I was gonna try and find a solution for you but it would take too much effort to make this runnable so I dont really have much of a solution for you ... you could always bind the EVT_CLOSE of the mainframe to `sys.exit`  I would think that would work for sure (even if its hackey and not really the "right" way)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I can provide a dummy class that extends wx frame after I get back from my lunch break if you'd like :)

Comment: We need a small, runnable example to be able to tell you what's wrong. I am guessing one or more of the children are either not parented correctly or they are not getting destroyed correctly, so one of them basically hangs and doesn't allow the main frame to close.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Unfortunately I cannot replicate this error with a dummy wx.Frame class. It works perfectly fine, but I have no idea which part of my other wx.Frame classes were causing the error. I'm not sure what to do right now since the other classes are 500 lines long and you surely won't want to read all of that. I'm considering on possibly closing this question since I can't provide concise details as to how this error occured.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about the parenting of the sub frames. All frames are created, butr they are initially not visible. If they are never shown, there is no way of destroying them, if they have no parent. The main loop will run forever. Try this minimal example:

```
import wx

class app_frm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.choices = {}
        # append frames
        self.choices['parent'] = wx.Frame(self, -1, 'I have parent')
        # try play around with the following two parenting option
        # see difference, when prent is None and the frame is never ``.Show()``n
        prent = self
        #prent = None
        self.choices['noparent'] = wx.Frame(prent, -1, 'I have no parent')

        self.key_map = {}
        pnl = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        for frm_nm, frm in self.choices.iteritems():
            btn = wx.Button(pnl, -1, 'Show frame {0}'.format(frm_nm))
            btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)
            self.key_map[btn.GetId()] = frm
            sz.Add(btn, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 4)
        pnl.SetSizer(sz)
        sz.Fit(self)

    def on_btn(self, evt):
        btnid = evt.GetId()
        frm = self.key_map[btnid]
        print 'EVT_BUTTON', btnid, frm
        frm.Show()

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frm_parent = app_frm(None, -1, 'I am parent')
frm_parent.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```